# Exclusively Locked File Detection AutoIt

Tags: autoit

How do I check to see if a file is exclusively locked in AutoIt? I am not talking about read/write access. Also, I have done some research, and if a file is locked, it does not show up in the task manager process list.

One example would be in Perl called flock:
You check to see if a file is locked via  $theRC = flock($HANDLE, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB);

I am trying to replicate this in AutoIt.

I have found one working solution:

```
Local $f = "C:/log.txt"

MsgBox(0, _FileInUse($f), @error)

;===============================================================================
;
; Function Name:    _FileInUse()
; Description:      Checks if file is in use
; Parameter(s):     $sFilename = File name
; Return Value(s):  1 - file in use (@error contains system error code)
;                   0 - file not in use
;
;===============================================================================
Func _FileInUse($sFilename)
    Local $aRet, $hFile
    $aRet = DllCall("Kernel32.dll", "hwnd", "CreateFile", _
                                    "str", $sFilename, _ ;lpFileName
                                    "dword", 0x80000000, _ ;dwDesiredAccess = GENERIC_READ
                                    "dword", 0, _ ;dwShareMode = DO NOT SHARE
                                    "dword", 0, _ ;lpSecurityAttributes = NULL
                                    "dword", 3, _ ;dwCreationDisposition = OPEN_EXISTING
                                    "dword", 128, _ ;dwFlagsAndAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
                                    "hwnd", 0) ;hTemplateFile = NULL
    $hFile = $aRet[0]
    If $hFile = -1 Then ;INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1
        $aRet = DllCall("Kernel32.dll", "int", "GetLastError")
        SetError($aRet[0])
        Return 1
    Else
        ;close file handle
        DllCall("Kernel32.dll", "int", "CloseHandle", "hwnd", $hFile)
        Return 0
    EndIf
EndFunc
```

Comment: Bah no syntax bot for autoit?

Comment: Highlight your code and click the `{}` icon in the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
Func FileInUse($filename)
    $handle = FileOpen($filename, 1)

    $result = False
    if $handle = -1 then $result = True

    FileClose($handle)

    return $result
EndFunc

;~ usage
$filename = "C:\Windu15f.exe"
if FileInUse($filename) Then
    MsgBox(0, "", "File is in use")
Else
    MsgBox(0, "", "Not in use - go nuts")
EndIf
```

Comment: Actually, Windows/NTFS (not sure which) allow different programs to open a handle to the same file at once. If you can obtain this lock via FileOpen, other programs can still open the file in read mode.